# Update single data in a coloumn in android sqlite database

Tags: android

I am trying to change a single value in a coloumn in android sqlite.
but i am not getting the result. My db query is given below

```
public Cursor update_MaxCrAmnt(String maxcramount, String accId){
    return db.rawQuery("UPDATE AccMaster SET Max_CrAmt=? WHERE Acc_No=? AND Bal_Type=?", new String[] {maxcramount, accId, "Cr"});
}
```

This method calling code is given below, amnt and accid are string values.

```
       try {
                db.open();
                db.update_MaxCrAmnt(amnt,accid);
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("Update error", ""+e.getMessage());
            }
```

Need your help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting the Cursor to contain? You are not selecting data...?!

Comment: i just want to change the value of Max_CrAmt to new value maxcramount

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**NB:Please Dont Use this method as there is chance of SQL injection when do like this**

```
String update = "UPDATE AccMaster SET Max_CrAmt = '"+ maxcramount +"' WHERE accId = " + accId +"AND Bal_Type= Cr";
db.execSQL(update);
```

Comment: This is clearly not good-practise due to possible sql-injection. One should use a parameterized statement!